# Ctags like function code search for javascript with Nodeclipse

Tags: javascript, ctags, nodeclipse

With nodeclipse, when i click on a function name, it doesn't take me to the module where the function definition is there (like ctags feature for c).
for example, say

```
var express    = require('express'); 
var router = express.Router();
```

Now when i click on the function call, Router() - i expect it to go to node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With tern (your project has .tern-project) when you mouse over `Router()` you should see Origin that is click-able.

[image]

read more

https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/New-and-Noteworthy-0.7.0

Nodeclipse main code
https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/

Tern.java
https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java

Raise issues, and be ready to collaborate.

Comment: when you say with tern, is it a plugin shipped along with nodeclipse (or) it needs to be installed from eclipse market place? i am asking this, because, for me on mouse hovering over the code, it shows only two fields - (Returns? with value as '?' ,Guess? as 'true').

Comment: Since 0.17 it is included with Marketplace or Install button option.
When it doubt, just update Nodeclipse / Enide Studio http://nodeclipse.org/updates/ Read more news and history